# Angular Server Side Rendering and PWA

Tags: angular, progressive-web-apps, server-side-rendering, angular-universal, angular-pwa

I've just added PWA functionality to my [invoice website](https://tuinvoice.com/). It's working fine but it broke the server side rendering, first pageview is OK, and requesting by CURL is ok too, but if you reload the page you get an ugly blink and the pre-translated text is shown.

I've been looking for fixes but I've found none, is it possible to force the browser to get the render from the backend always except if it's offline? Any other solutions online?

I'm using Angular 7

Comment: Is there any error in the console?

Comment: No errors, everything works fine, but the experience is worse than normal SSR, I think I'll just remove PWA...

Comment: Also I saw this github issue, looks like it's something normal and there's no fix https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/26739

Comment: Yes, I have also saw that post from github. That's a shame that it still an open issue.